# Team explorer 2010 error on project node?

Tags: tfs

Not directly programming, but related:

I'm using team explorer 2010 to connect to a 2010 TFS server (On a 2008R2 box), however when I try and connect, I get a red X on the project node and cannot expand it. There are not error messages or anything. Here is an image of what I am getting [image]. I have the same exact setup on another system (except Windows 7), using the same credentials and it works fine. Anyone ever run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

Run `devenv.exe /ResetSettings`
If this won't help, you'll have to do a clean install of VS 2010 Ultimate (preferably Ultimate)

Answer (score 0):

I get this every once in a while.

To resolve this, I delete the cache folders in the %APPDATA%..\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache folder.

Go the steps from [here](http://my2centsontfs.blogspot.com/2012/01/tfs-client-cache-cleanup.html).